# What does three terms in a typedef mean?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

What does it mean when there are three items in a typedef?

For example:

```
typedef CK_BYTE     CK_PTR       CK_BYTE_PTR;
```

I know that if you just have `typedef CK_BYTE CK_PTR`; then `CK_BYTE` would just be able to be referred to as `CK_PTR`.

Comment: Post how those 2 other terms are defined.

Comment: `CK_BYTE` and `CK_PTR` are probably either typedefs or macros. How are they defined?  Does `CK_PTR` expand to `*`, by any chance? (If so, it serves mainly to obfuscate.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A bit of Googling indicates that `CK_PTR` is a macro defined in [`pkcs11.h`](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/sonmi/Linux2.4_x86_glibc_PTH_DBG.OBJ/include/pkcs11.h).  Follow that link to see the documentation for these definitions.

It's normally defined as:

```
#define CK_PTR *
```

but on some ancient systems it might be defined as

```
#define CK_PTR far *
```

where `far` is a mostly obsolete system-specific keyword that specifies a certain non-standard kind of pointer.

So this:

```
typedef CK_BYTE CK_PTR CK_BYTE_PTR;
```

is equivalent to this (much clearer) code:

```
typedef CK_BYTE *CK_BYTE_PTR;
```

which defined `CK_BYTE_PTR` as a pointer to a `CK_BYTE`.

The quoted definition of `CK_BYTE_PTR` occurs in the same header file.

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a lot! I would give you a vote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 3):

It's not valid syntax, unless one of those is a macro (e.g. `#define CK_PTR *`, which is horrid).

Comment: It's not *quite* as horrid as it looks; it's intended to hide the `far` keyword on ancient x86 systems.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks! Its defined like that in another file, any idea why someone would do this?

Comment: @m3hughes: Keith's answer seems to cover this (+1 to him!).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `CK_PTR` is defined as `*` you are typedef'ing a `CK_BYTE*` as a `CK_BYTE_PTR`.